# MySQL is not null equivalent to >= '' in a where clause? And which performs better?

Tags: mysql, null

Given the following select statement:

```
select starttime,id
          from childattendance
         where endtime is null
           and starttime is not null
           and date < date('2018-05-24')
           and companyid = 1414;
```

Would I get the same results 100% of the time if I changed it to this:

```
select starttime,id
          from childattendance
         where endtime is null
           and starttime >= ''
           and date < date('2018-05-24')
           and companyid = 1414;
```

It seems to me that if a field has a non null value then it's always greater than or equal to an empty string, not so?

And if this is true, then which performs better?

Answer (score 0):

The two statements can never be equal because in mysql NULL is very different from "". When a field is NULL, it means no value has been set to that fied. On the other hand, if a field value is "", its the same as saying that the field has an empty string as a value.

Comment: I understand that a null is different than a blank, but in regards to the query won't the results always be the same either way?

Comment: It wont be the same because NOT NULL != ''